# What does it mean for a parameterised path to be spherically symmetric?

Tags: symmetry, coordinate-systems

This question seems embarrassingly simple, but I was wondering what it means for an object to be spherically symmetric? I've been working through some questions where I'm told to use this fact to help simplify working with paths in space.

I understand what this means intuitively (maybe), but am having difficulty expressing this condition mathematically. Say we have a parameterised path given by:

$\sigma(s)=(r(s), \theta(s), \phi(s))$

What does it mean for this to be spherically symmetric? Some people have suggested this means $\frac{d\theta}{ds}=\frac{d\phi}{ds}=0$

Thinking about this, I initially thought about a circle which is (I think?) is a spherically symmetric path, i.e. the path in polar coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$ given by:

$x(s)=(R, 2\pi s, 0)$,

where $R$ is fixed and $s\in[0, 1]$

This doesn't have $\frac{d\theta}{ds}=0$, which makes me think the condition must be something else? Or is the circle not a spherically symmetric path because it isn't the same in ALL directions (eg. $\phi\ne 0$). In this case, any idea what could my books be referring to when they talk about using spherical symmetry to simplify working with paths?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of a *path* being spherically symmetric.  Do you have a particular context for this?

Comment: The reason I decided to ask is because I have seen it twice so far. Once in general relativity, where we are considering a 'spherically symmetric path' in a spherically symmetric field. The second was a similar situation in electromagnetism.

Comment: I suspect it may simply be bad phrasing. However clearly both the book and lecturer were getting at some point, even if they did express it poorly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer might not be truly correct by "definition", but I'm going to attack it from a different viewpoint. I am inspired by the action $J$ of a functional

$$ J = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x,y,\dot y)dx $$
as in Lagrangian mechanics. You can solve this problem to solve the geodesics of physical geometries. For example in Euclidean space, the functional is $ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{1+{\dot y}^2}dx$, which minimizes to a linear solution $y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)$ in applying Lagrange's equations.

Here $ds$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, which are all of the independent coordinates belong to that that 2D space. Now let's go to your example of the circle: in polar coordinates, we write a general displacement as
$$ dr = \sqrt{dr^2 + (rd\theta)^2} $$
But in the case of a circle, the radius does not change over the movement, so
$$ ds = rd\theta.$$
Here, I would say the circle has spherical symmetry because the displacement - or from my inspiration, the functional minimized to uncover its geodesic - maintains a constant radial distance $r$ with respect to the other variables.

Properly I believe you should write $$d\vec{x} = dr{\hat r} + rd\theta \mathbf{\hat{\theta}},$$

which collapses to a circular displacement in the limit of $r \rightarrow 0$. The real condition I think for spherical symmetry resulting of this is

$$ \frac{dr}{d\theta} = \frac{dr}{d\phi} = 0 $$
which is to say that $r$ remains constant under changes of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Now for your position vector $\vec{x}(s) = (R, 2\pi s,0)$. Differentiate with respect to your parameter $s$:
$$ \frac{d\vec x}{ds} = (0, 2\pi, 0),$$
which is a circular path of $2\pi$ radians. Here we needed to satisfy $\frac{dR}{ds} = 0$ for the circle, which is certainly does.

Here $ds = \frac{1}{2\pi}d\theta$ so we have the condition that $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = 0$ hidden there.